# how to create a multi line chart in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, charts, multiline

i want to create a c# graph (multi line) I've already connected it with a sql server data base to fill the series and it work for one line but the other line didn't work 
the first line don't show up in the chart but second do, i have to series enumerated as 0 and 1 "only (serie 1) work)
please someone check up the code if you can help with it

```
// dashboard
        ArrayList joursvisites = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList nombrevisites = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList nombreventes = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList chffreAffaire = new ArrayList();

        #region dashboard
        private void ventes_visites()
            {
                 string connstr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connstrng"].ConnectionString;

                 using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connstr))
                 {

                      string query = "SELECT cast(d.Jours AS INT) as jours, count(d.ID_Visiteur) as nombre_visite, " +
                      "cast(count(dl.ProduitChoisit) AS INT) as nombre_ventes, " +
                      "cast(sum(dl.PrixPayé) AS INT) as chiffre_affaire " +
                      "FROM dbo.Deal as dl JOIN dbo.DateVisite as d " +
                      "ON dl.ID_Date = d.ID_Date " +
                      "GROUP BY d.Jours " +
                      "ORDER By Jours ASC";

                       SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);

                       con.Open();
                       SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                       while (reader.Read())
                       {
                           joursvisites.Add(reader.GetInt32(0));
                           nombrevisites.Add(reader.GetInt32(1));
                           nombreventes.Add(reader.GetInt32(2));
                           chffreAffaire.Add(reader.GetInt32(3));
                       }

                      chart1.Series[0].Points.DataBindXY(joursvisites, nombrevisites);
                      chart1.Series[1].Points.DataBindXY(joursvisites, nombreventes);
                      chart2.Series[0].Points.DataBindXY(joursvisites, chffreAffaire);

                      reader.Close();
                      con.Close();   
                 }
            }
        #endregion
```

Comment: 'Doesn't work' is not a helpful problem description! Tell exactly what happens! Also: You really should set the x&yvaluemembers for each series!

Comment: i set the and i want the same chart (chart 1) to contain two lines(nbr of visit and nbr of sales) i fill the two series from the data base but only one showed up in the chart (serie 1)

Comment: Your code works fine here. - Also: ArrayList is depracted, use List<T> instead! Do check your values!! Most likely the data are bad.

Comment: i used lists but it still the same only the second line showed up the first don't

Comment: ArrayList works but it should no longer be used. If the 2nd line won't show, you need to look at the data! We can't do that for you. Use the debugger to look at the yValues of the datapoints of the 2nd series! Sometimes they are of a greatly different scale than those of the 1st and will look like all 0s.. Comment out the line that binds the 1st line to test..!